# How to gracefully exit Bottle when a Timer runs in the background?

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard-events, bottle

When I start my bottle app, an object creates a forever running timer:

```
from threading import Timer

class Watcher(object):
    def __init__(self, timer=Timer):
        self.timer = timer
        self.watcher_interval = 2 * 60 * 60
        self.check_condition()

    def check_condition(self):
        do_stuff()
        self.timer(self.watcher_interval, self.check_condition).start()
```

This works fine.

However, I am now unable to quit the application by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> as the Timer still runs in the background.

How can I tell the Timer to quit, when sending the keyboard interrupt? As of now, I have to either kill it via its PID or if I am feeling lazy by `killall python`.

Answer (score 0):

Timers inherit from Thread, so when creating your timer, specify that it is a [daemon thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) by setting its `daemon` instance variable to `True` (before starting it); doing so will cause it to terminate when Python determines that no non-daemon threads are running.